# finding 2nd largest element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to find the 2nd largest element from an array..so the easiest way I found is sorting and getting the required element at specified index...

m done with d sorting using `Comparator`.

```
public static final Comparator<car> PriceComparator = new Comparator<car>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(book b1, book b2) {
        return b1.price - b2.price; 
    }    
};
```

Now how to get the second largest price value...and even I have to display the other details of the book. I have attributes like book name, price, capacity.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are refering to cars or books?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and get the 2nd index object from list. It's easy way or you looking something else?

Answer (score 0):

To sort, use:
    Arrays.sort(array_name, car.PriceComparator);

Then take the second value.

Shouldn't your comparator be for class book, though, if you're comparing books? As another additional note, class Car should be capitalized to follow Java naming conventions.